# getting data from external json url in yii2 framework

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

i have to get data from externaljson url api in yii2 framework,json url is:https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/EympRaB4D

```
<p>
       <input type="button" value="Fill SELECT Dropdown List with JSON" id="bt" />
   </p>
   <select id="sel">
       <option value="">-- Select --</option>
   </select>
   <p id="msg"></p>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#bt').click(function () {
           var url = "https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/EympRaB4D";
           $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
               $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                   // APPEND OR INSERT DATA TO SELECT ELEMENT.
                   $('#sel').append('<option value="' + value.company + '">' + value.country + '</option>');
               });
           });
       });
       // SHOW SELECTED VALUE.
       $('#sel').change(function () {
           $('#msg').text('Selected Item: ' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
       });
   });
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you add some more details or precise what's the problem?

Comment: <p>
       <input type="button" value="Fill SELECT Dropdown List with JSON" id="bt" />
   </p>
   <select id="sel">
       <option value="">-- Select --</option>
   </select>
   <p id="msg"></p>

Comment: <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#bt').click(function () {
           var url = "https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/EympRaB4D";
           $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
               $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                   // APPEND OR INSERT DATA TO SELECT ELEMENT.
                   $('#sel').append('<option value="' + value.company + '">' + value.country + '</option>');
               });
           });
       });

Comment: // SHOW SELECTED VALUE.
       $('#sel').change(function () {
           $('#msg').text('Selected Item: ' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
       });
   });
</script>

Comment: this is the code i tried in yii2

Comment: Can you edit that in your question?

Comment: @PrasannaKumarReddySamanthula , Please check out my answer and please add some comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#bt').click(function () {
           $.ajax({
               url: "https://next.json-generator.com/api/json/get/EympRaB4D",
                type: "GET",
                success: function (result) {
                    //console.log(result);
                    for(var dataSet in result){
                        $("#sel").append("<option value="+result[dataSet].company+">"+result[dataSet].country+"</option>");
                    }
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
           });
       });
       // SHOW SELECTED VALUE.
       $('#sel').change(function () {
           $('#msg').text('Selected Item: ' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
       });
   });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <input type="button" value="Fill SELECT Dropdown List with JSON" id="bt" />
        </p>
        <select id="sel">
            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
        </select>
        <label id="msg"></label>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have already this code brother ,iam posted this for code in yii2 framework

Comment: @PrasannaKumarReddySamanthula , I have added a working code. Wait 5 seconds after clicking on the button `Fill SELECT Dropdown List with JSON` because your API takes time to provide a response. So please tell me what is your actual problem.

Comment: I have missed one thing that is disable the  button `Fill SELECT Dropdown List with JSON` after a button click. So you can add it by putting the following code after the `for loop` in the `success section` : `$("#bt").attr("disabled", true);` . Thank you @PrasannaKumarReddySamanthula